# Como puedo deshabilitar varios controles simultaneamente?

Tags: java

Pense que al agrupar todos los ***controles*** en un mismo **panel** de java podria deshabilitando el **panel** deshabilitar todos los controles pero resulta que no es asi... Hay alguna forma parecida a lo que intento explicar o otra forma que no sea uno a uno?

Comment: Escribir un método que agrupe todas las deshabilitaciones que quieres realizar y llamar al metodo cuando quieras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un trozo de código antiguo que tengo para realizar diferente tareas sobre todos los componentes de un contenedor.
Simplemente añade el código para desabilitar los componentes y la comprobacion del contenido de los scrollpane

```
public static void vaciarPanel(Container a){

    for(int j=0;j<a.getComponentCount();j++){

      if(a.getComponent(j) instanceof JPanel){
        vaciarPanel( (JPanel) a.getComponent(j));
      }
      else if(a.getComponent(j) instanceof JTabbedPane){
        for(int i=0;i<((Container)a.getComponent(j)).getComponentCount();i++){
          if(((Container)a.getComponent(j)).getComponent(i) instanceof JPanel){
            vaciarPanel( ( (Container) a.getComponent(j)).getComponent(i));
          }
        }
      }
      else if(a.getComponent(j) instanceof JScrollPane){
        for(int i=0;i<((JScrollPane)a.getComponent(j)).getViewport().getComponentCount();i++){


        }
      }else{
         // Codigo para los componentes
      }
   }
}
```

El código es muy mejorable, pero es muy antiguo. Pero sirve para lo que quieras hacer de forma global en los contenedores

limpiar,
desactivar,
comprobar contenido, 
etc

Comment: muchas gracias me funciona bien

Comment: Solo tengo una duda en la limpieza de los componentes que exactamente tengo q poner ahí por ejemplo si tengo un panel con 3 textfield como se limpian?

Comment: en el ultimo else tienes que poner a.getComponent(a).setEnabled(false); Si lo que quieres es limpiar el contenido, tienes que determinar el tipo de componente y hacer un setText("") para losTextField o un clear() para las listas, etc.

Comment: gracias me di cuenta ayer... nuevo lenguaje nuevos retos...